# Should these <head> elements be presented in an alternative order or method?

Tags: html, meta-tags, head

I have a few questions regarding the following header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="content">
<meta name="keywords" content="content">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/canonical.php" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400|Cabin+Condensed:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Note: I've omitted the `http:`/`https:` protocol per [Google's guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml)

1. Is the Order of the elements ok? i.e., not sure where `Title` should be - before or after all meta tags?
2. I've read on the guide it's better to merge all stylesheets into one, should I do it?
3. Should I also try to merge both local .js files into one? if so, does the order of the merged content matter?
4. Per the guide, I've omitted all `type` indicators (no `type="text/css"` or `type="text/javascript"`), would this be ok even with older browsers such as IE7?
5. any other things I should take note of?

Answer (score 0):

1. The order you have is typical and acceptable.
2. Merging your CSS depends on how you're using them.  The more css styles the longer it takes to load the page so you don't want to load too many unnecessary css styles.  I suggest including all of your common styles in a main css stylesheet (style.css) then your additional css sheets can be added page specific.
3. Your js should follow the same concept as css.
4. Haven't heard about that, probably safest to leave the type attribute.
5. you should move your script files out of the head after your main html in a footer tag.  This prevents your main page waiting to load until the scripts load, especially when including a large script file like jquery.

Comment: thanks, are you sure about #5? I'm pretty sure websites always put the jquery inside the `head` tag...

Comment: yes,they often do put them in the <head>, but since browsers read files from top to bottom, it will need to load the entire jquery file before loading the rest of your html.  A script can be placed anywhere in a file.  Best practices place all scripts in external files and in the <head> but for an improved user experience, placing it at the bottom is better. It doesn't need to be in a <footer> tag necessarily, just after the rest of you html.

Answer (score 0):

1 - `X-UA-Compatible` should be closest to the `head` tag.

2+3 - Merging css/js files is a good option when you have a relatively large amount of files (like 20 and above). It's good mostly for large sites. Note that older browsers have a limit of the amount of js/css files they can load per page.

4 - The guide is for browsers that support HTML5 so maybe a year from now it will be a default for all active browsers. For now you'd better keep the types.

5 - Like @kcdev wrote, placing the js files at the footer can help load your page faster, but if you start an action that calls for a function that haven't been loaded yet it will result in an error. so, it's up to you.